# Select immediate sibling in CSS or jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I am going round in circles but not able to find a precise logic for this. I have a following code:

```
<form>
 <table></table>
 <div class="1"> </div>
 <div class="2"> </div>
 <div class="3"> </div>
</form>
```

The table tag dependence is controlled via setting and it is not always present. What I want to do is to hide "div" with class 1 if the "table" tag is present. Any idea as to how I can do this via CSS or Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *+* to express immediate sibling:

```css
table + div.one {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table></table>
  <div class="one">a</div>
  <div class="two">b</div>
  <div class="three">c</div>
</form>
```

Comment: There is no need to duplicate your code blocks. Stack Snippets always display the code within your post.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('table').length > 0 ? $('.class1').hide() : $('.class1').show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <table></table>
 <div class="class1"> 1</div>
 <div class="class2"> 2</div>
 <div class="class3"> 3</div>
</form>
```

1. Assuming that only one table exist use `.length` to check if present.
2. You can use ID or class to be more specific of the table to check.
3. Dont start naming class using number

For specific table:

```js
$('table#check').length > 0 ? $('.class1').hide() : $('.class1').show();//checks for table with id check if present then do hide or show
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table id='check'></table>
  <div class="class1">1</div>
  <div class="class2">2</div>
  <div class="class3">3</div>
  <table id='check1'></table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/8a1a12zh/)

Using `.siblings()` method.

```
if ($('table').length > 0) {
  $("table").siblings().first().hide();
}
```